# OpenCV Homography - The 4 line not around the object

Tags: android, opencv

I try to do [this](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html#feature-homography), and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18335346/activitythreadsource-not-found) .his question is not what I want to ask, but I want to do the same thing. I can find features and draw feature descriptors on image , but the bounding box around the object was very weird .Sorry, I can't post my result on here ,The line came out is not a rectangle , is not around the object [here is my result](http://answers.opencv.org/question/24127/findhomography-the-line-come-out-not-around-object/), what I doing wrong or it have another way to do it?

Sorry for my poor English,Thanks for the help

```
    private void Featrue_found(){       

    MatOfKeyPoint templateKeypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfKeyPoint keypoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();

    Object = new Mat(CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Object = Highgui.imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Files/Object.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Resource = new Mat(CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Resource = Highgui.imread(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Files/Resource.jpg", Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
    Mat imageOut = Resource.clone();        


    FeatureDetector myFeatures = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.ORB);       
    myFeatures.detect(Resource, keypoints);
    myFeatures.detect(Object, templateKeypoints);

    DescriptorExtractor Extractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    Mat descriptors1 = new Mat();
    Mat descriptors2 = new Mat();
    Extractor.compute(Resource, keypoints, descriptors1);
    Extractor.compute(Resource, templateKeypoints, descriptors2);

    //add Feature descriptors
    DescriptorMatcher matcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.BRUTEFORCE);
    matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

    List<DMatch> matches_list = matches.toList();

    MatOfDMatch good_matches = new MatOfDMatch();
    double max_dist = 0; double min_dist = 100;

    //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows(); i++ )
    { 
        double dist = matches_list.get(i).distance;
        if( dist < min_dist )
            min_dist = dist;
        if( dist > max_dist )
            max_dist = dist;
    }

    //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 3*min_dist )
    for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows(); i++ )
    { 
        if( matches_list.get(i).distance < 3*min_dist ){
            MatOfDMatch temp = new MatOfDMatch();
            temp.fromArray(matches.toArray()[i]);
             good_matches.push_back(temp);
        }
    }

    MatOfByte drawnMatches = new MatOfByte();       
    Features2d.drawMatches(Resource, keypoints, Object, templateKeypoints, good_matches, imageOut, Scalar.all(-1), Color_Red,  drawnMatches, Features2d.NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS);
    //no Feature descriptors
    //Features2d.drawMatches(Resource, keypoints, Object, templateKeypoints, matches, imageOut);

    LinkedList<Point> objList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    LinkedList<Point> sceneList = new LinkedList<Point>();
    List<DMatch> good_matches_list = good_matches.toList();

    List<KeyPoint> keypoints_objectList = templateKeypoints.toList();
    List<KeyPoint> keypoints_sceneList = keypoints.toList();

    for(int i = 0; i<good_matches_list.size(); i++)
    {
        objList.addLast(keypoints_objectList.get(good_matches_list.get(i).queryIdx).pt);
        sceneList.addLast(keypoints_sceneList.get(good_matches_list.get(i).trainIdx).pt);
    }

    MatOfPoint2f obj = new MatOfPoint2f();
    obj.fromList(objList);

    MatOfPoint2f scene = new MatOfPoint2f();

    scene.fromList(sceneList);
    //findHomography 
    Mat hg = Calib3d.findHomography(obj, scene);

    Mat obj_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);
    Mat scene_corners = new Mat(4,1,CvType.CV_32FC2);

    obj_corners.put(0, 0, new double[] {0,0});
    obj_corners.put(1, 0, new double[] {Object.cols(),0});
    obj_corners.put(2, 0, new double[] {Object.cols(),Object.rows()});
    obj_corners.put(3, 0, new double[] {0,Object.rows()});
    //obj_corners:input
    Core.perspectiveTransform(obj_corners, scene_corners, hg);

    Core.line(imageOut, new Point(scene_corners.get(0,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(1,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(imageOut, new Point(scene_corners.get(1,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(2,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(imageOut, new Point(scene_corners.get(2,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(3,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);
    Core.line(imageOut, new Point(scene_corners.get(3,0)), new Point(scene_corners.get(0,0)), new Scalar(0, 255, 0),4);

    Highgui.imwrite(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/Android/data/" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + "/Files/result_match.jpg", imageOut);


}
```

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I would say there are too few features in the image you are looking for... And I can not check because of the resoultion, but are you sure the found matches are ok? Or are they misplaced?

Comment: found matches was ok , but the bounding should around object is misplaced

Answer (score 0):

Number of matches are not enough in your case. Also matching is not correct. For best result I would suggest using RANSAC in homography calculation and change the threshold of good matches.

```
    if( matches_list.get(i).distance < 3*min_dist ){
        MatOfDMatch temp = new MatOfDMatch();
        temp.fromArray(matches.toArray()[i]);
         good_matches.push_back(temp);
    }
```

make 3*min_dist to be 4*min_dist and check if good feature matching is there. If not then you should opt for some other feature detector(SURF, SIFT,harrison) Harrison might give noisy result, but it will produce maximum number of feature points. Or if none of these works then work with better image quality image.